# Proving a proposition involving the argument of a complex number

Tags: proof-verification, complex-numbers

> Suppose $z,w \in \mathbb{C}$. Show that $\arg \overline{z} = - \arg z \mod 2 \pi  $ and $\arg( \frac{z}{w} ) = \arg z - \arg w \mod 2\pi$.

#### Attempt

Let $z = r( \cos \theta + i \sin \theta )$. So, $\arg( z) = \theta \mod 2\pi$. Notice $\overline{z} = r( \cos \theta - i \sin \theta ) = r ( \cos(- \theta) + i \sin( - \theta ))$ since $\cos$ is even and $\sin$ is odd. We have $\arg \overline{z} = - \theta = - \arg z  \mod 2 \pi $.

Next, write $z = r_1e^{ i \theta_1} $ and $w = r_2 e^{i \theta 2 }$. So $ \arg z = \theta_1 \;  \mod 2 \pi $ and $\arg w = \theta_2 \; \mod 2 \pi $. We have

$$ \frac{z}{w} = \frac{r_1}{r_2} e^{i(\theta_1 - \theta_2) }$$

Hence, $\arg \frac{z}{w} = \theta_1 - \theta_2 = \arg z - \arg w \; \mod 2 \pi$

Is this sufficient to show these formulas?

Comment: Sounds correct to me

Comment: I also believe it's correct.